# hiebrnate projection with distinct

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to get the distinct on my column "testType" in table "Test".
Also I want to get both "testType" and "testId" in my list. For that I am doing this
but it doesn't applying the distinct , giving me the duplicate result.

Any idea how can I resolve this?

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
proList.add(Projections.property("testType"));
proList.add(Projections.property("testId"));
crit.setProjection(proList);
crit.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
List rsList = crit.list();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

to get the distinct values of testType

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
List results = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
    .setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("testType")))
    .list();
```

but to get the id as well you can't select for it since there may be many ids for each Type, e.g.:

```
testId | testType
-----------------
1      | type1
2      | type2
3      | type1
4      | type2
6      | type3
7      | type3
```

what should `Select Distinct(testType), testid` return?

1. (type1, 1), (type2, 2), (type3, 6)
2. (type1, 3), (type2, 4), (type3, 7)
3. (type1, 1), (type2, 4), (type3, 6)

1)

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
List results = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.group(Projections.property("testType"))))
        .add(Projections.Min(Projections.property("testid")))))
    .list();
```

2)

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
List results = session.createCriteria(Test.class);
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.group(Projections.property("testType"))))
        .add(Projections.Max(Projections.property("testid")))))
    .list();
```